# How to remove big play button shadow in Video.js?

Tags: css, html5-video, video.js

I am looking for help on how to remove the small shadow in the triangle play button in video.js.  I have tried playing around with the CSS for the element ".vjs-big-play-button" and box-shadow/text-shadow.  However box-shadow will only change the shadow for the whole play button and text-shadow didn't change anything.

Thank you.

I have uploaded an image to show exactly which shadow I am trying to remove:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr0fh.png

Answer (score 0):

To get this all you have to do is edit the class that is rendering the play icon. It looks like this in the css file:

```
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-big-play-button:before {
  content: @play-icon;
  font-family: VideoJS;
  /* In order to center the play icon vertically we need to set the line height
     to the same as the button height */
  line-height: @big-play-height;
  text-shadow: 0.05em 0.05em 0.1em #000;
  text-align: center /* Needed for IE8 */;

  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Removing text-shadow should get you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines after css embed inside :

```
<style>.vjs-default-skin:hover .vjs-big-play-button, .vjs-default-skin .vjs-big-play-button:focus {box-shadow: none;}</style>
```